# gradle how to add only javascript files to a directory in the war file

Tags: gradle, war

I am trying to create a web application that uses angular2. The part of the build.gradle responsible for compiling the typescript and adding it to the war is as follows:

```
public class TsCompileTask extends DefaultTask {
    File projectDir;

    @OutputDirectory
    File outputDir;

    @TaskAction
    void compile() {
        println "compiling TypeScript files..."
        project.exec {
            executable = "tsc"

            args "-p"
            args projectDir
            args "--outDir"
            args outputDir.toString()
        }
    }
}

public class npmInstallTask extends DefaultTask {
    File projectDir

    @TaskAction
    void compile(){
        println "installing npm packages"
        project.exec {
            workingDir = projectDir.path
            executable = "npm"
            args "install"
        }
    }
}

task tsCompile(type:TsCompileTask) {
    projectDir = file('./src/main/typescript')
    outputDir = file("$buildDir/ts")
}

war{
    into("js"){
        from tsCompile.outputs
    }
}
```

This adds the output of the typescript compiler to the js directory in the war archive, but it does not add the dependencies, which are in the directory node_modules.

I tried to use the following gradle snippet to add only the JavaScript files from the typescript directoryinto thw war:

```
war{
    into("js"){
        from fileTree(dir: './src/main/typescrypt/').matching{
            include('**/*.js)
        }.files
    }
}
```

However, this includes all files under the directory.

I have tried several variations of the above (e.g. having the into be in a closure for from instead of the other way around, using `fileTree('./src/main/typescript').include('**/*.js')`). How can I add **only** the files ending in .js to the js directory in the war file?

Comment: I strongly advise to stop reinventing the wheel. Use angular-cli to build your angular project. That will generate a dist directory containing all the bundled, optimized artifacts. Integrate the angular-cli build (and the node and npm installation) in the gradle project using the following gradle plugin: https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin

Comment: @JBNizet I could try using angular-cli for this particular project, but what I'm asking how to do would be useful in **a lot** of other situations.

Comment: This is not really gradle related. You need your JavaScript build (using webpack, gulp, whetever you want), to produce a directory containing all the artefacts you want to embed in your war. Gradle just needs to embed this directory inside the war.

Comment: @JBNizet I respect your knowledge of how to make angular projects and am in the process of applying your advise, but the ability to use Gradle to take all files with a certain suffix and put them in an artifact is still something that looks like it would be very useful. Do you know how I would do that?  This particular project uses angular which has a way around the problem, but I can easily see this problem appearing in other situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `from` method takes strings, not file objects.

```
war{
    into("js"){
        from fileTree(dir: './src/main/typescrypt/').matching{
            include('**/*.js)
        }.files.stream().map{
        File->file.toString()
    }.collect(Collectors.toSet())
}
```